# Mongo linking one array to another

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, lookup

The starting point for this query is a collection called books:

```
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'isbn': 8765434567890,
   'booktitle': 'some text',
   'chapters':
      [
         {
            'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01kkk333"},
            'pagenr': 7,
            'title': 'whatever',
         },
         {
            'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01dj3jd7f"},
            'pagenr': 12,
            'title': 'another title',
         },
      ]
}
```

There's of course much more to it. But this collection is the starting point for the query.

A second collection has notes about a lot of things in various collections, amongst others about the chapters in the above collection:

```
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01kkk333"},
   'note': 'blabla',
},
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d888hhh"},
   'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01kkk333"},
   'note': 'more blabla',
},
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "55353536504f1f01d000000"},
   'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416swldkjfdskjl34"},
   'note': 'blabla',
},
```

So more notes can be about the same chapter. Linked by the **r_id** oid in both collecions.

What I need is two almost similar things:

**1** Get the complete record of one book by the **isbn** nr.
And add the **amount of notes per chapter** to that record.

**2** Get the complete record of one book by the **isbn** nr.
And add **all of the notes per chapter** to that record.

**NB** The chapters are not ordered in the collection, but should be ordered by chapters.pagenr in the output.

So the output for **1** would be something like:

```
{
   '_id' {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01d773faa"},
   'isbn': 8765434567890,
   'booktitle': 'some text',
   'chapters':
      [
         {
            'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01kkk333"},
            'pagenr': 7,
            'title': 'whatever',
            'notes': 2
         },
         {
            'r_id': {"$oid": "64ba6a416504f1f01dj3jd7f"},
            'pagenr': 12,
            'title': 'another title',
            'notes': 0
         },
      ]
}
```

For **2** notes would of course contain the array of notes. Almost the same, but not.

What I've come up with so far:

```
match = {'$match': {'isbn': {'$in': isbns}}}
project = {'$project':
        {
            '_id': '$_id',
            'isbn': '$isbn',
            'booktitle': '$booktitle',
            'chapters': {'$sortArray':
                {
                    'input': {'$map':
                                  {'input':
                                       '$chapters',
                                   'in': {
                                       'pagenr': '$$this.pagenr',
                                       'title': '$$this.title',
                                       'r_id': '$$this.r_id',
                                       }
                                   }
                              },
                    'sortBy': {'pagenr': 1},
                }
            },
            'notes': '$$related_notes',
            
      }
}
lookup = {'$lookup':
        {
            'from': 'notes',
            'localField': 'chapters.r_id',
            'foreignField': 'r_id',
            'as': 'related_notes',
        },
}

pipeline = [
        lookup,
        match,
        project,
    ]
```

This works, the notes are of course added to the end of the output. If I put them in the $map part, they are repeated numerous times and not filtered in any way.

By the way, coming from SQL, I really love Mongo. It's marvelous however not easy to grasp. Learning a lot about it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: sth like https://mongoplayground.net/p/tIRfuoyHptJ maybe

Comment: also bring the match before lookup to avoid unnecesary lookup

Comment: So the $lookup simply generates an array and with $filter you select the relevant items from that array. And $filter returns an array, hence the $size. Is it that simple?

Comment: yes filter returns an array.for the case pagenr': 7 it returns an array of 2 notes. by wrapping it in size you get the length of the returned array from filter. in the playground link i provided you can check by removing the `$size` operator to see what comes

Comment: Now, digging deeper. There's a User_id (oid) in each Note. And via $lookup an array of users from the collection users. How can we connect the relevant user to each note? Same approach?

Comment: yes connecting has to be done using lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$filter` inside each map iteration where you filter the `related_notes` array to return an array which has notes having `r_id` of that particular iteration. Then you can get the size of the filtered array using `$size`.
Also you can do the `$match` before `$lookup` to reduce unnecessary lookups

```
db.books.aggregate([
  { $match: { isbn: { $in: isbns } } },
  { $lookup: { from: "notes", localField: "chapters.r_id", foreignField: "r_id", as: "related_notes" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      isbn: "$isbn",
      booktitle: "$booktitle",
      chapters: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$chapters",
              as: "chapter",
              in: {
                r_id: "$$chapter.r_id",
                pagenr: "$$chapter.pagenr",
                title: "$$chapter.title",
                notes: { $size: { $filter: { input: "$related_notes", as: "note", cond: { $eq: ["$$note.r_id", "$$chapter.r_id"] } } } }
              }
            }
          },
          sortBy: { pagenr: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FoDOmSRrUzk)